# Script async how does it actually work and when to use it

Tags: html, asynchronous

According to MDN:

> Async...indicate that the browser should, if possible, execute the script asynchronously

The definition is really vague. So let me phrase my understanding explicitly and please correct me if I am wrong:

**My first question** is that When I use the keyword async to load a 3rd party script, the browser will continue to parse the DOM elements after the  tag while downloading the script via **a different thread**. I want to know how browsers actually implemented the `asychnoronous`.

Is my interpretation correct?

**My second question** is that When would be a good situation to use `async` instead of `defer`? (I understand the differences between them, I just don't know when would be the case to use one instead of the other)

Let's say a script I want to include does not have any dependencies and it is not depend upon by other scripts. Why is it recommend to use `async` in this case instead of `defer` other than the difference in execution timing?

Comment: Use async if no other scripts is depending on your script; use defer if they do.

Comment: Let's assume there is no other script depends on a script that I am about to include. What's wrong with using defer? It's just the execution timing of the script is different, but are there any other benefits of using async?

Comment: http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2014/02/async-vs-defer-attributes.html might help

Comment: @ChrisLear Thanks again for the chart. I understand that async gets executed as soon as the script is downloaded and defer will wait until the dom is loaded. But is there really a benefit of executing a script as soon as it downloads vs waiting till the dom loads?

Comment: It's a bit quicker. That's about it.

Comment: @ChrisLear according to the link you sent, the execution is quicker sure, but while it is executing, it actually blocks dom parsing. So I am not sure if it is quicker overall. You just simply moved a piece of code around but everything is still executed synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what the spec says:

https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/script.html#script.attrs.async

`async` Specifies that the script should be executed asynchronously, as soon as it becomes available.

https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/script.html#script.attrs.defer

`defer` Specifies that script should be executed after the document has been parsed.

Comment: I appreciate your links but I already know the differences. I am wondering how they are implemented in the browser. What does it actually mean to be `executed asynchronously`?

Comment: It means that the script is not executed in a strict sequence. If you have a series of commands executed synchronously, prior commands are always completed before the later ones are begun. An `async` script will be executed when it finishes loading, and therefore its execution will be at an unpredictable time with respect to other scripts on the page. A sort of analogy is a click event. You don't know when it will occur, but you can attach code to it. That code needs to be isolated from assumptions about what else is going on at the time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/748175/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-execution-what-does-it-really-mean is probably helpful here.

Comment: Let me reword again. There are two aspects to `async`. One is downloading the script and two is executing the script. I want to know how the browser handled the downloading part. Does it just spawn a thread so that it can download the script in parallel of parsing the DOM?

Comment: I can't actually back this up with a source code reference, but I'm almost certain that the download aspect is identical in both cases. `async` can execute earlier in the process than `defer`, and exactly when it executes is not predictable. That's the main difference between the two. Threads are implementation-dependent.